# Receiving typeError x is not a function on code

Tags: javascript

(disclaimer, still very much learning and searching for this hasn't helped) I can't understand what I'm doing wrong with this code.

```
let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

let overusedWordsCount = betterWords.filter(function(word) {
  if(overusedWords.includes(word)) {
    return overusedWords++; 
  } else if(overusedWords.includes(word)) {
    return overusedWords++;
  } else if(overusedWords.includes(word)) {
    return overusedWords++;
  }
});
```

I get TypeError: overusedWords.includes is not a function, but I have absolutely no idea why. I wrote something similar that works, which is why I'm confused.

```
let storyWords = story.split(" ");

let unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually' ];

let betterWords = storyWords.filter(function(word) {
    if(!unnecessaryWords.includes(word)) {
     return true
     } else {
     return false
     }

  });
```

I'd really appreciate any help, still very new to this.

Thanks

Comment: You’re overwriting `overusedWords` by doing `overusedWords++`. `overusedWords` is an array, not a number, so `++` doesn’t make sense there. Just `filter` it with `return !unnecessaryWords.includes(word);`, then check its `length`. There may be a better way, but this depends on what `betterWords` actually is in your first snippet.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do in your code...

Comment: On what line is the error?

Comment: @JosanIracheta It’s on `if(overusedWords.includes(word)) {` at the second iteration. I already explained why this occurs in the first comment.

Comment: Thank you @Xufox - that makes a lot of sense now. I didn't realise that I was overwriting it when I was putting overusedWords in the codeblock.

I've been trying to get the output of words from paragraph string! I could have explained it better, sorry.